# Is it possible to get data from the relationship table of a relationship table in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Say I have 3 tables

```
Users
- id
- name

Phones
- id
- number
- user_id

Carriers
- id
- name
- phone_id
```

In `Models`, I set all necessary `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relations.

I can select `user` with `phones` using:

`App\User::with('phones')->where('id', '=', 1)->first();`

and `phone` with `carrier`:

`App\Phone::with('carrier')->where('id', '=', 1)->first();`

Is it possible to get a collection which has both `phone` and `carrier` using model `App\User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$users = App\User::with('phones.carriers')->get();
```

Or,

Setup [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation in user model:

```
   public function carriers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Phone', 'App\Carrier');
    }
```

so that you can get both carriers and phones:

```
$user->carriers;
$user->phones;
```